# Enable slick only under a certain window width and disable it when window width turns bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, breakpoints

I am writing a blog that shows posts with a slick carousel ONLY when the viewport is a certain value, so on mobile devices is it possible to scroll them.

I tried a lot of ways but none was successful.
Various problems occurred.

The code snippet closest to my goal is the following:

```
function slickify(){
    $('.goslick').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 500,
                     settings: "unslick"
                }
            ]
     });
                }
    slickify();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if ($windowWidth > 500) {
            slickify();   
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately this does the opposite of my goal; it enables the carousel when the viewport is bigger than the value indicated by the relative variable. I really can't reverse this script.

[Here is the not-working prototype](http://www.matteocorona.com/cms_images/archivio_bs.php)

Comment: `if ($windowWidth` **<** `500)`?  Won't disable it when it gets bigger, but the enabling part should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Please is not so obvious to me :(

Comment: "If *less-than* then doSomething."  You have "if *greater-than* doSomething" where the "something" is making it mobile friendly.

Comment: Please read the comment to the Adam Konieska answer, it seems obovious, but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I made it working with this snippet:

```
         function slickify(){
            $('.goslick').slick({
                autoplay: false,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            });
          }

          $(window).resize(function(){
              var $windowWidth = $(document).width();
              if ($windowWidth < 500) {
                  slickify();   
              }else{
                  $('.goslick').slick("unslick");
              }
          });
```

Note that I removed the call of the slickify() function out of the window.resize and I replaced windows.width with document.width in order to prevent that the slick loads bad going back to the page or starting it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something to undo code executed in your `slickify()` function.  You're calling `slickify();` right off the bat, so its going to execute.  You just need to add an else statement to do something different when the window size is less than 500.

```
function slickify(){
    $('.goslick').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 500,
                 settings: "unslick"
            }
        ]
     });
}

function deslickify(){
    //todo logic here to disable 
}


slickify();

$(window).resize(function(){
    var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($windowWidth > 500) {
        slickify();   
    } else {
        deslickify();
    }
});
```

### Edit:

This *should* be working as you have it.  It looks like you've taken working code from this SO question: [Enable and disable Slick Slider on certain break points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098833/enable-and-disable-slick-slider-on-certain-break-points)

```
function slickify(){
    $('.slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        delay: 5000,
        speed: 700,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 500,
                settings: "unslick"
            }
        ]
    });
}

slickify();
$(window).resize(function(){
    var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($windowWidth > 500) {
        slickify();   
    }
});
```

And it can be seen working on this JS fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/steveambielli/7weuyn4c/

It appears something in your implementation is causing some abnormality.  Implementing the code from the other SO question *should* work.  If you are getting specific errors or issues post them and we can further debug.

Comment: if I write "$('.goslick').unslick();" into deslickyfy function it still doesn't work. The same if i change the sign ">" with "<".
It doesn't works even if I write "$('.goslick').slick({
         dots: false,
         infinite: true,
         speed: 300,
         slidesToShow: 1,
         slidesToScroll: 1,
             responsive: [
                 {
                     breakpoint: 1024,
                      settings: "unslick"
                 }
             ]
       });" into the deslickify function. It seems obvious, but it is not.

Comment: Something else must be happeneing.  You've copied the code exactly from this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098833/enable-and-disable-slick-slider-on-certain-break-points and that *should* work.  Can you revert it to that state and we'll try and troubleshoot it further?

Comment: @MatteoCorona that example is working.  What was yours doing before you added the code from my answer?

Comment: The informations of the various post are imported by a php script at the top of the html page. It get all from a database with a query and fetching them all. The I fill the html parts with a foreach. I am usingboot strap. I deleted all the javascript code that there it was before the yours, but the problem isalways the same. If u want, I can sendto you the entire code of the page.